# How to make collection header stay on top and collection items scrollable?

Tags: css, meteor, materialize

I have navigation bar, filter and collection in one of my layouts in SPA - following in exact that order. Nav bar, filter and collection header must stay on top when scrolling, only collection items must be scrollable. I managed to make the whole collection scrollable, but it's not quite what I want.

```
<div class="navbar-fixed">
  <nav>...</nav>
</div>
<div class="row">...this is filter...</div>
<div id="collection-wrapper">
  <ul class="collection">
    <li class="collection-item"></li> <!-- serves as header --> 
    <li class="collection-item"></li> <!-- shows data -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

Using perfect-scrollbar on #collection-wrapper: https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `max-height` of the `collection` list to specific value that will allow the list to scroll. Setting the `position` of the first `collection-item` to `fixed` will prevent that item from scrolling with the rest of the list.

```
ul.collection {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
  list-style-type: none; /* not sure if you need this. Hides bullet list dots */
}

li.collection-item:first-child {
  background-color: white; /* should be the same as the background color behind the list */
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Had to adjust width and top properties of first collection-item to make header blend in, but basically that's it. Thank you.